# Disable download pop up Firefox Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am very new to Selenium and I am typing up my first script to download a .csv file from a webpage.

Problem is, when I click the button to download the .csv file a download window pops up. How do I automatically save the file to a folder?
I tried a variety of profiles but I can't seem to get them to work.

Comment: found a solution

```fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain, application/octet-stream, application/binary, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, text/comma-separated-values, text/xml, application/xml")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",0)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the below configuration in one of my project

You can possibly have this firefox profile, In Python you could this :

```
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\***\\****\\Desktop\\Automation")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, executable_path = "Full file path to gecko driver.exe")
```

Comment: I am getting a error at profile = FirefoxProfile()
It's a undefined name. What should I do to make yours work?

Comment: Import this `from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile`

Comment: You seem very knowledgable so I may as well ask you here. Do you know how I can run the application in headless mode? Everytime I try, it still opens the browser.

Comment: Figured that out, 
```options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, executable_path = 'C:\geckodriver.exe', options=options)```